# Use single JWT Token with 2 different applications

Tags: jwt, system-design

I have 2 different applications.
Let's say A & B.
A is being used for login/signup and users related activities.
And It is also used for Generating JWT Token and validation as well.

Now, the other application B is used for some very specific operations.
I want to use the same JWT token I generate from application A to validate users and extract useful information from the token.

Can someone please suggest to me what design should I follow?
Should I use 2 different JWT validators?

Answer (score 1):

Actually is nothing wrong to use service A as an Authorization Service that issues JWT tokens and the B service as a resource service

here is a posts described how to do it in ASP.NET Web API

[Token based authentication](https://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)